# Advantages of the LM algorithm over Quasi-Newton

Tags: numerical-methods, numerical-optimization

I have an optimization problem that I'm solving using matlab, I didn't pay much attention to what kind of problem was except that it wasn't linear. So I solved it using a `quasi-newton` algorithm. However I realized this morning that my problem can be written in the form

$$
f(x) = \frac{1}{2}\sum_j r_j(x)^2
$$

Which should allow me to use an LM (Levemberg-Marquadt) solver. I do wonder however in case I'd switch what kind of benefit LM can give me over the current algorithm.

Can it be faster much faster maybe?

As far as I know `quasi-newton` are a family of direction search algorithm, while `LM` is a special case of trust region approach specialized for non linear least square (according to my references at least).

I can see a possible memory advantage, because in my case the Jacobian would be sparse, but what about speed? is there anything I can say?